# How to handle a Login event for a specific auth guard?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5 application with multiple authentication guards.

I created a `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login` event listener which handles the login event but I can't come up with a way to only handle the event for a specific authentication guard.

Comment: you can either create multiple login event based on user type or in event filter the user type and you can dispatch services accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check in your listener if the user is logged via that specific guard. If true, do your normal stuff.

```
if(Auth::guard('web')->check()){
    // Do normal stuff
}else {
    // If you want an else.
}
```